# Order query for Azure Sync table

Tags: android, azure, sql-order-by

I am using Azure services for android.
I am using syncTable and i am getting data from the service.
But i want to order the coming data .
Anyone knows how to do it?
following is the code :

```
 //fetching data from syncTable
  mToDoTable= mClient.getSyncTable("ToDoItem",ToDoItem.class);
```

i am getting all data on button click like following :

```
private void initElementsWithListeners() {
    btnTableData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toDoDao.getAllDataFromTable(mToDoTable);

        }
    });
```

but i want the data coming from the service should be ordered by "fieldName" for the sync table. how should i do that ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

@swanandvaidya, According to the [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-offline-data/), you can create a `Query` for your MobileServiceSyncTable to order data by a specified field, please see the code below.

```
mToDoTable = mClient.getSyncTable("ToDoItem", ToDoItem.class);

// Offline Sync
final List<ToDoItem> results = refreshItemsFromMobileServiceTableSyncTable();

private List<ToDoItem> refreshItemsFromMobileServiceTableSyncTable() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    //sync the data
    sync().get();
    Query query = QueryOperations.add()
         .orderBy("<fieldName>", QueryOrder.Ascending); 
    // or using `QueryOrder.Descending`
    return mToDoTable.read(query).get();
}
```